# Pass arguments between Webapp2 redirects

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to redirect URL without slug, to the one with slug, at the `urls.py` level.

My endpoints looks as follows:

```
(r'/invoices/<:(-?\d+)>/print/', PrintHandler, 'ShortPrintHandler')
(r'/invoices/<:(-?\d+)>/<:([\w-]*)>/print/', PrintHandler, 'FullPrintHandler')
```

Is there any way I can pass first, `decimal`, argument from short URL to the long one, on redirect? Generating URLs without `slug` is already covered at handler level.

Tried to handle it with

```
RedirectRoute(r'/invoices/<:(-?\d+)>/print/', PrintHandler, redirect_to_name='FullPrintHandler')
```

But an error was thrown:

```
KeyError: 'Missing argument "1" to build URI.'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with just a RedirectRoute; you need to get the slug value from somewhere.

You'll need to write a standard route, and in the handler you should get the object from the datastore and return a redirect to the full path using the slug.

Something like (untested):

```
class RedirectToFullPath(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, invoice_id):
        invoice = Invoice.get_by_id(invoice_id)
        self.redirect_to('FullPrintHandler', invoice_id, invoice.slug)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the answer. Just to make sure we are on the same level,
When I use Full Print URL (the one with slug required), I get object from the datastore compare slugs, and then redirect to the full path using the slug, just as you mentioned.

What I want to achive is to redirect 'short' url without the slug, to the 'full' one, passing 'ID' in between requests, then missing slug will be  pulled from datastore, and user will be redirected. 
So user tries to access:
`/invoices/1/print`
Is redirected to
`/invoices/1//print`
and missing slug will be handled at handler level